# How to simulate rare events with extremely low probability

Tags: simulation, rare-events

Suppose I have a time series with $2\times 10^8$ data points. One kind of rare event will happen at each time point with an equal and extremely low probability of $1\times 10^{-8}$.
Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Comment: Search for "importance sampling"

Answer (score 2):

In principal, you can estimate the probability that a total of $n$ rare events will occur over the length of the entire $N = 2 \times 10^{8}$ data points using a binomial distribution: $$P(n) = \left( \begin{array}{c} N \\ n \end{array} \right) p^{n} (1-p)^{N-n}$$ and setting $p = 1 \times 10^{-8}$.  In practice, in limiting cases such as this where $N \rightarrow \infty, p \rightarrow 0$ while $Np = \mu$, the binomial distribution can be well approximated by a Poisson distribution.  A discussion of how to derive the Poisson distribution from the binomial distribution can be found [here](http://www.le.ac.uk/users/dsgp1/COURSES/LEISTATS/poisson.pdf) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#law_of_rare_events).  Thus, in your case, with a high degree of accuracy you can model the probability distribution of a given number of rare events $n$ occurring over the entire observation interval using: $$P(n) = \frac{\mu^{n} e^{-\mu}}{n!}$$ where $\mu = (2 \times 10^{8}) \cdot (1 \times 10^{-8}) = 2$.

Comment: +1 Welcome to the site, @stachyra. This is a really nice answer: clean, authoritative, concise, & easy to understand. I hope we'll see more like this in the future.